# Need to exceed the 8k record limit when using wide columns/sparse tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, database-administration

Need to exceed the 8k record limit in SQL Server 2008 when using wide columns/sparse tables.

Long story new client old system using survey system, pivoting data so all answers are a column

I have 1500 columns and now I am getting

> Cannot create a row that has sparse data of size 9652 which is greater than the allowable maximum sparse data size of 8019.

I need to exceed the 8k record limit if possible

Comment: It is not possible; the 8K limit is a hard, unchangeable system-wide and system-imposed limit. No way to get around it, no way to configure it to be more than 8K

Comment: A work-around could be to get the records as rows instead of columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not possible, because SQL Server stores rows on 8K pages. The only way to do so would be to store some of the data off-row (e.g. using MAX or other LOB types for some of your columns). To your application, this will still look like it's on the same row, even though logically it is on a complete different area of disk.

If your sparse column set alone exceeds the limit, sorry, you'll need to look at a different way to store the data (either not pivoted, EAV, or simply use two tables joined by a key, each containing half of the column set). For the latter you can make this relatively transparent to users by using views and/or enforcing all data access / DML through stored procedures that understand the division.